# How to set a CSS settings only to the td of an external table but not to the internal table?

Tags: html, css, layout, xhtml

I am working on a legacy web page that use a table layout (that unfortunately I can't replace with a new pure HTML\CSS layout) and I have the following problem.

I have a situation like this:

```
<table class="externalTable">
    <tr id="firstRow">
        <td>
            <div>
                <table id="tablistOn">
                    <!-- SOME ROWS ARE SHOWED -->
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td>SECOND td</td>
        <td>THIRD td</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to applied a `bottom-border` property only to the `#firstRow` row and I do in this way:

```
.externalTable #firstRow td, .externalTable #firstRow th {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

but doing in this way the problem is that this style is applied also at all the tows inside the internal table rows (the one having `id="tablistOn"`).

I think that I can override it defining a new style for this table but I am asking if I can apply my style only to the external table selecting only the `class="externalTable"` table but not its inner table `id="tablistOn"`.

How can I do it in some way?

Tnx

Comment: using `>`; `.externalTable #firstRow > td` . Then it will just apply style to next `td` only

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't `#tablistOn` in the *first* row of `.externalTable`?? Or don't I understand the question correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using descendant selectors, which will match *all* children within an element. What you need are child selectors - `>` - which will only select *direct* descendants of an element.

```
.externalTable #firstRow>td, .externalTable #firstRow>th {
    border-top:1px solid red;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

- [More information on child
  selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)
- [More information on descendant selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors)
- [More information on selectors in
  general](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
.externalTable #firstRow td, .externalTable #firstRow th {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

#firstrow table td {
    border: none;
}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can write two ways to solve this.

1.

```
#externalTable  td{
// One Style
}

#tablistOn td{
// One Style
}
```

2

```
#externalTable  td:not(#tablistOn td) {
// Styles
}
```